# wrong number of arguments for initialize_with factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have this factory code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cost_group, class: CostGroup do
    transient do
      user_id     nil
      cost_object   nil
    end

    initialize_with { new(attributes) }
  end
end
```

and this is my class:

```
class CostGroup
  attr_reader :user_id, :cost_object

  def initialize(user_id, cost_object, data = {})
    ...
  end
end
```

but I am getting error while running specs.

```
let(:u) {build(:user)}
let(:cost) {build(:cost)}
let(:cost_group) { build(:cost_group, user_id: u.id, cost_object: cost) }
```

this results with: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)` on `initialize`. Why this show this error message when I am passing arguments? And why not 0 but 1? Is that all I passed is getting grouped to 1 argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mainly because of `initialize_with { new(attributes) }` as `attributes` here is a hash.

you will need to make it manually `initialize_with { new(user_id, cost_object) }`

Comment: Oh yes, this helped, thanks. Before I was trying `initialize_with { new(user_id: user_id, cost_object: cost_object) }` with no luck, but your answer works for me.